# Google Drive API: Insufficient Permission iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using google drive API.When i try to fetch file from drive using

```
  let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
  let service = GTLServiceDrive()
  query?.pageSize = 1
  query?.fields = “files”
  service.executeQuery(
      query!,
      delegate: self,
      didFinish: #selector(self.displayResult(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
 )
```

I am getting error like

> "The operation couldn’t” be completed.(Insufficient Permission).

Anyone knows which permission I need to setup in dashboard?

Comment: You have activate drive api in google api console if not than activate

Comment: Please check this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth

Comment: What scope are you using to authenticate?  @Lalitkumar that is not the not enabled in developer console error.

Comment: I already active drive api in my console.and @Dalm To I am using oAuth for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to make use of a Google Sign In, if users shall access a non-public file. Or you are interested in a user related files list.

To do so, request at first a sign in. Make sure to also set the UIDelegate of the Google Sign In, to have a present the login screen at the correct point of time: `GIDSignInUIDelegate`. To present it, you can call:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

If users had been signed in already, you can call:

```
if userSignedInBefore {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
}
```

Assuming you got your request being called in a specific class like this (used for illustrating the idea):

```
class Requester {
    static let service = GTLServiceDrive()

    static func fetchData() {
        let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
        query?.pageSize = 1
        query?.fields = “files”
        service.executeQuery(query!, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(self.displayResult(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
    }
    ...
}
```

In addition, you will need a delegate of `GIDSignInDelegate` this one will take care and store a user's related information, when a user logs in:

```
// https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        //            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        //            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        // ....
        // Here you will receive an authorizer instance that implements the GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol protocol.
        // This authorizer instance will be required by your GTLRDriveService services as authorizer reference.
        // https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_authentication
        var authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

        // Here you can trigger any callback to now fetch the desired data
        Requester.service.authorizer = authorizer
        Requester.fetchData()
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

For more information or a sample implementation have a look at Google's documentation:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios